# VBSCRIPT not working to run program with parameter and not hidden

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch script that is working by running the below program but decided to change it because the window of the application is not hidden and also blinking everywhere on the screen. I decided to use VBScript, but I am now struggling to implement the same thing on VBScript running the application with the same parameter that works with the batch file. I initially run the program without the parameter using VBScript, and it opens the program but does not hide it. Two things I need.

1. How to run the program with the parameter and hide it.
2. if the loop can be implemented with the parameter as well

   ```
         :: Innitial working batch script :

         FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,114) DO (
           rem  ECHO %%i

         "C:\Program Files (x86)\Example Heli\HFDM Converter\HFDM_CONVERTER.EXE" "C:\HFDM_converter\Arinc 717 Description\H175_STEP2+_FDCR_converter_configuration_file_v4.xml" "C:\HFDM_converter\Gilda Directory\H175_V5.1R6.0_GILDA_V2501_FDCR_converter_delivery" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Example Heli\Process_fdc" "C:\archive" %%i pcm /ae  /s /hp /ss /sn

         )
   ```

---

```
::VB Script to help with ::

Dim objShell
Set objShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


a= ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Example Heli\HFDM Converter\HFDM_CONVERTER.EXE""
b= ""C:\HFDM_converter\Arinc 717 Description\H175_STEP2+_FDCR_converter_configuration_file_v4.xml""
c= ""C:\HFDM_converter\Gilda Directory\H175_V5.1R6.0_GILDA_V2501_FDCR_converter_delivery""
d= ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Example Heli\Process_fdc""
e= ""C:\archive""

objShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Example Heli\HFDM Converter\HFDM_CONVERTER.EXE"" b c d e 004 pcm /ae  /s /hp /ss /sn", 0, false
```

Comment: Change your batch file to use START "" /B "C:\Program Files (x86)...HFDM_CONVERTER.EXE" etc. You can get info on using START by typing START /? at a command prompt.

Comment: No that is not what I want. The problem is that HFDM is an application itself and it comes with its own console and it keeps open after each loop is completed in another position of the screen. The only thing to do now is to hide it immediately it is lauch and am having problem with this. I will look at autoit if it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to go with autoit. here is the code : Thanks

```
Local $i
sleep(2000)

For $i = 1 To 300 Step 1
    sleep(100)

    ;;; MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Count down!" & @CRLF & $i)
RunWait('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Examples Heli\HFDM Converter\HFDM_CONVERTER.EXE" "C:\Program Files (x86)\AIRBUS HELICOPTERS\HFDM Converter\Arinc 717 Description\H175_STEP2+_FDCR_converter_configuration_file_v4.xml" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Examples heliHFDM Converter\Gilda Directory\H175_V5.1R6.0_GILDA_V2501_FDCR_converter_delivery" "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\Unconverted" "C:\FDM\Upload" ' & $i  & ' pcm /ae /s ' )

sleep(50000) ;;;; very important because if many fcd in a folder, the hfdm converter might close to move to the next fcd and you do not want to jump the loop quickly
Next
```

Comment: If you managed to solve your own problem, don't forget to accept your own answer by clicking the tick. :)